# sql server integration services Issue

Tags: ssis

Q 1. what is the difference between SSIS consume webservice and normallly access webservice through website?

Q2. what is the difference between consume webservice through web task and In script component (through as web reference)?

Q3. which one is better for consume webservice?

Answer (score 0):

When I've tried to use the web services tasks and sources in SSIS i've felt that there were significant limitations as to how you have to call it the web services in SSIS. Frequently a web service will require you to pass in parameterized URL's which requires a dynamic construction of the URL. The best thing that I've found for this is to use the Script Task (C# or VB, take your pick) so that you can construct the endpoint URL to specifications.